# Change week definition in pandas resample

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, when I use the pandas resample function for days to weeks it uses a Sunday to Saturday week, but I'd like it to use a Monday to Sunday week.  Is this possible?  I tried using `loffset` from the docs, but it doesn't change the data at all.

`pivot_news = pivot_news.resample('w', 'sum')`

Comment: Can't you just subtract a day and then resample?

Comment: Would it suffice to drop the Saturday rows before the resample? Edit: ninja'd by EdChum, I think he means exactly the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `freq='W-MON'`. For example:

```
>>> dates = pd.Series(np.arange(30),
...                   index=pd.date_range('2015-10-1', periods=30, freq='D'))

>>> dates.resample('W', 'sum')
2015-10-04      6
2015-10-11     49
2015-10-18     98
2015-10-25    147
2015-11-01    135
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: int64

>>> dates.resample('W-MON', 'sum')
2015-10-05     10
2015-10-12     56
2015-10-19    105
2015-10-26    154
2015-11-02    110
Freq: W-MON, dtype: int64
```

You can find more information [in the Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets)